# Как реализовать такую анимацию на чистом html+css?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такую анимацию на html+css?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Готовое давать не хочу, но вот вам ключевые слова для поиска: `@keyframes`, `animation`, `animation-delay`, `opacity`

Comment: А вообще ведь можно тупо воткнуть гифку как есть и это будет чистый html даже без css :D

Comment: Можно конечно гифку воткнуть, но нужно без гифок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться свойством [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation), в котором можно устанавливать анимации заданные с помощью [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) и настраивать скорость, задержку и продолжительность анимации.

Позаимствовав сердечко с сайта [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), можно получить следующее

```css
.heart {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  animation: 1.3s opacity_change linear infinite;
}

.h1 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.h2 {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.h3 {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.h4 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.h5 {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.h6 {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.h7 {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.h8 {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 25px;
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ff00de;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

@keyframes opacity_change {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="heart h1"></div>
<div class="heart h2"></div>
<div class="heart h3"></div>
<div class="heart h4"></div>
<div class="heart h5"></div>
<div class="heart h6"></div>
<div class="heart h7"></div>
<div class="heart h8"></div>
```